# Trouble installing pg

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, homebrew, pg

I've been trying to install an api that says to use

```
bundle install
rails s
```

But when I do bundle, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot 
continue. Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`succeeds before bundling.
```

But when I run that gem install command, I get this:

ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20191018-63874-el2g8s.rb extconf.rb checking for pg_config... yes Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
```

And the mkmf.log file says:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/BuildRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl/lib'
```

I'm not really sure where to start, as I've followed a good amount of other guides online and they either don't work or lead me to new errors.

Comment: did you install xcode? If not you need to.

Answer (score 0):

[Install brew](https://brew.sh). This will take care of any dependencies like Xcode's command line tools. Run this command in your terminal to install brew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

When brew has successfully installed, install PostgreSQL with:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Then retry:

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Please note that the gem version specified is almost five years out of date.

Comment: Don't you need to first do `xcode-select --install` before install homebrew?

Comment: On a fresh installation of Catalina the other day it did this automagically for me.